# Help identifying the various series in the Toonami 'Advanced Robotics' commercial

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, episode-identification

This classic Toonami commercial for 'Advanced Robotics' contains a mashup of a few different robot/mecha-centric franchises but I don't recognize them all.

[Toonami Advanced Robotics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kziSDTpAaOA)

Can I get some help listing the various series? Here are the ones I recognize without knowing the specific movie or series:

1. Dragonball/Dragonball Z
2. Gundam
3. Justice League Unlimited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

0:00 - 0:28 - *The Big O.* First episode.

0:28 ("It's coming") - ???

0:29 - 0:35 - Probably *Gundam Wing*.

0:35 - Dragon Ball Z. Probably main series. I suspect they're operating on Frieza after his defeat.

0:38 - *Superman The Animated Series*. I believe this advert predates the Justice League cartoons.

0:42 (and the voiceover that overlaps previous) - *Gundam Wing*

0:43 - 1:08 - *The Big O*. Spliced from multiple episodes. The explosion at the end could be from another series.

1:10 - *Gundam Wing*

1:14 - *Superman The Animated Series*. Episode collection *The World's Finest*, a crossover with Batman TAS

1:16 - Dragon Ball Z, probably the film *The World's Strongest*

1:26 - Possibly *Outlaw Star*

1:29 - *Gundam Wing*

1:31 - Definitely *Dragon Ball Z: The World's Strongest*

1:37 - *Blue Submarine No. 6*

1:51 - Animation is from *The Big O*. The voiceover is not. Google suggests it's from Gundam, but I can't pin it down. Possibly 08th MS Team.

The [Toonami wiki page](https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/Advanced_Robotics) lists the shows used and the original air year.

Comment: I had not heard of 'The Big O'. It looks interesting.

Comment: I think 0:28 is also Gundam Wing