# What are these classic 80's action movies?

Tags: story-identification, movie, character-identification

I've bumped into an exquisite 80's music+TV compilation on YT. Since I was born in the early 80s, I missed most of these movies at the time. Of course I did later watch most classic, iconic and cult movies that are still shown in regular cable TV today and are easily recognizable. That being said, I fail to identify a great deal of those featured in this clip. Specifically, I'm interested in the name of the movies shown at:

1. [2:41:01](https://youtu.be/dfda5aEwbnA?si=U_mnqe6tNaiz8CJx&t=9661) unknown sci-fi anime movie/series
2. [2:41:07](https://youtu.be/dfda5aEwbnA?si=a0YTOOOm1qPuUeK7&t=9667) unknown sci-fi movie

***What I've tried so far***: Google Lens, and manually searching on IMDB, but the clips in the video are so short that the only possible way to identify most clips is by actually watching the corresponding movies/series.

Comment: Only sci-fi and fantasy is on topic here, so please remove any non-sci-fi non-fantasy movies from the question. (Unfortunately no one knows just what "sci-fi" or "fantasy" is, so use your best judgement.)

Comment: Apart from anything else, the first two timestamps clearly point to outtakes from the same scene of the same movie.

Comment: The 3rd might be Cowboy BeBop. but that just based on style, I dont know. The 4th is from Blade Runner (1982).  https://www.exrey.tv/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/blader-runner-3.jpg

Comment: The second clip Is a Jackie Chan movie, Police Story (1985) (The bus fight is quite famous),  UNLESS you meant the scene after the bus clip. Which as @Buzz pointed out IS the same movie as clip #1. But with the watermark I cant see the actor's face.  But to me it looks like a woman.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed because 1) only SF allowed here 2) 1 ID per question, multiple IDs not allowed. When you repost as single questions, its perfectly OK to use screenshots.

Comment: @NJohnny Maybe scene #4 refers to the "blue floating face" scene rather than the Blade Runner one (which is really famous).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this, as I think it does _not_ contain a bunch of unrelated questions but rather asks to identify several sci-fi scenes from a definite source, not unlike [other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171218/40711) [character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/220860/40711) [identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/253083/40711) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267719/40711) that were well received (having screenshots would definitely improve the question, though)

Comment: Thanks @NJohnny, indeed I meant the bus scene. Feel free to add it as answer when the question is reopened, I'll never understand the terror that users around here have to post answers, and everyone keeps using the comments feature to respond. As someone else pointed out I was referring to the blue floating face scene, I've already seen Blade Runner w/my father countless times. ;)

Comment: @lfurini You are right I meant the blue face scene, no one has identified that one yet. I've edited the question to comply with the staff policies.

Comment: @andreszs - The first clip is from _Yes, Madam_ (1985). As noted by NJohnny, the second clip with the bus scene is from _Police Story_ (1985). As noted by lfurini, the third clip is from _Akira_ (1988). (Please consider marking lfurini's answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer.) If you post a separate question asking about the fourth clip, I can answer that for you.

Comment: Aww nuts, i've only just seen this, but yes:  [1:15:15] is none other than Cynthia Rothrock kicking in 'Yes, Madam' (1985); [1:15:50] Jackie Chan's bus scene in 'Police Story' (1985) ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFo_NjgwJbQ ); 'Akira' and 'Time Bandits'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The scene at [2:41:01](https://youtu.be/dfda5aEwbnA?si=U_mnqe6tNaiz8CJx&t=9661) (white spherical explosion between tall dark buildings) is from 1988 iconic anime masterpiece [*"Akira"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_(1988_film)), in particular from the penultimate scene.

Screenshot from the linked YouTube video:
[image: Screenshot from youtube video]

Screenshot from the movie (time code 1:51:22 in the DVD I checked):
[image: Screenshot from movie Akira]

Answer (score 25):

The "blue floating face" in scene #4 is from [Time Bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bandits):

Comment: But which answer should the OP mark as accepted? They're both equally correct. That's why [I asked them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281408/expert-required-to-identify-these-classic-80s-action-movies#comment776172_281408) to post a separate question regarding the fourth clip.

Comment: Probably would have been better to either ask separate questions or create a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer that anyone could add to, but I don't mind if OP just marks the Akira comment as accepted.

Comment: Oh no - missing out on internet points!